# Flutter FCM token can only push once on iOS release mode

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-ios

I ran to problem with FCM where:

- I run flutter ios app in release mode
- Then code firebase_message token to push notification
- Then Terminate App
- Then push notification using postman (see below)
- Get notification one
- Then push again but get "error": "NotRegistered"

```json
{
    "to": "fcm_token",
    "priority": "high",
    "data": {
        "NotificationTitle": "RequestJ",
        "NotificationBody": "Request"
    },
    "content_available": true,
    "apns-priority": 5
}
```